# Convert render to small video in Reinforcement learning

Tags: python, mp4, reinforcement-learning

Below is the sample code for simulation of atari games:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gym
import time
env =gym.make('BreakoutNoFrameskip-v4')
print("Observation Space :",env.observation_space)
print("Action Space :",env.action_space)
env.reset()
for i in range(1000):
    action =env.action_space.sample()
    obs,reward,done,info =env.step(action)
    env.render()
    time.sleep(0.01)
    if done :
        env.reset()
env.close()
plt.show()
```

The question:

- Is it possible to create a simple video from the render? So my question is whether it is possible to convert render to mp4 format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This saves a video of every `video_every`'th episode to the folder "video" while maintaining rendering to screen functionality from your post.

```
import gym
import time
env = gym.make('BreakoutNoFrameskip-v4')

video_every = 1
env = gym.wrappers.Monitor(env, "./video", video_callable=lambda episode_id: (episode_id%video_every)==0, force=True)

print("Observation Space :",env.observation_space)
print("Action Space :",env.action_space)
env.reset()
for i in range(1000):
    action =env.action_space.sample()
    obs,reward,done,info =env.step(action)
    env.render()
    time.sleep(0.01)
    if done :
        env.reset()
env.close()
```

Comment: thank you my friend. i would know in future